# Given $f^{\prime} = g , \, g^{\prime} = f$, Prove $f = \sinh, \, g = \cosh$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives

I'm having some trouble proving these rigorously

Given $f, g\,\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,$ differentiable with $$f^{\prime} = g \quad \text{and}\quad g^{\prime} = f$$

First, if $f(0) = g(0) = 0$, Prove that $f = g = 0$

Second, if $f(0) = 0$, $\,g(0) = 1$, Prove that $f = \sinh$, $\,g = \cosh$

Any suggestions?

Comment: "egreg" 's answer is very good except that it doesn't get involved with what mathematicians normally consider rigorous reasoning. My answer does that but takes up where egreg's left off, so the two combined answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"egreg" directed your attention to a certain function called (capital) $F$ and the fact that $F'=F,$ and then asked what you can say about $F.$

From one less-than-rigorous point of view, one might say that if $\dfrac{dF}{dx} = F\vphantom{\frac{}{\displaystyle\int}}$ then $\dfrac{dF} F = dx$ and then integrate both sides, getting $\log |F| = x +\text{constant},$ so that $|F| = (e^x\times\text{positive constant}),$ so that $F= (e^x\times\text{nonzero constant}).$ Of course, writing $\dfrac{dF} F \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$ assumes $F$ is not $0$, so you have to examine whether $F=0$ is a solution (and of course it is), etc., etc.

**However**, if one wishes to be logically **rigorous**, one may ask how we know that $F(x) = ce^x$ are the **only** solutions, and here's one way:

Suppose $F' = F.$

Let $H(x) = \dfrac{F(x)}{e^x}.$

Then by the quotient rule,
\begin{align}
H'(x) & = \frac{e^x F'(x) - e^x F(x)}{e^{2x}} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{e^x F(x) - e^x F(x)}{e^{2x}} \text{ since } F'=F \\[10pt]
& = 0.
\end{align}
Thus $H$ is constant and so $F(x) = (\text{constant}\times e^x).$

Hence there are no other solutions.

The above tacitly uses the mean value theorem, so let us make that not so tacit:
$$
\frac{H(a)-H(b)}{a-b} = H'(c) = 0,
$$
therefore $H(a) = H(b),$ for all $a,b;$ hence $H$ is constant.

(The reason for working with $\dfrac{F(x)}{e^x} \vphantom{\dfrac{}{\displaystyle\int}}$ rather than with $\dfrac{e^x}{F(x)}$ is that the former assures us that the denominator will nowhere be $0.$)

Answer (score 8):

Consider $F=f+g$ and $G=f-g$; then
$$
F'=f'+g'=g+f=F
\qquad
G'=f'-g'=g-f=-G
$$
What can you say about $F$ and $G$?

Comment: I up-voted this. What do  you think of my answer?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'd use $e^{-x}F(x)$ and the product rule: it's easier.

Comment: oh. True enough$\,\ldots\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Each of these functions satisfies $h''=h$. Do you know the general form for functions that satisfy this?

Comment: No, don't think I am aware of it.

Comment: Since the functions are self reproducing under two derivatives: $h''=h$, try $h=A e^{\lambda x}$ with $\lambda$ constant since the exponential is self-reproducing.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'm looking into this solution now. Since we didn't discuss solving differential equations during our lectures, is there possibly another way to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite this problem as a differential equation. For example, we know that $f''=f$ which is equivalent to saying $f''-f=0$ which constitutes a differential equation. If you write out the general solution to this equation, which happens to be $f(x) = A\sinh(x) + B\cosh(x)$ , and then apply the initial conditions given to you, you will find the answer.